# Sending file and text through one form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file

I'm trying to send file and text at the same time, but I end up sending only file. For some reason form ommits the text. Here's my code

```
<form action="test.html" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        Choose file
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="check">
   <input type="text" id="variable">
   <input id="but" type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()">
</form>
```

And here's my Javascript code

```
function send() {
     document.getElementById("variable").value = 1;
     var val = document.getElementById('check').value;
if (val != "") {
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
} else {
    alert("Choose file!");
  }
}
```

Note - it's important to me that the "variable" value will be added via JS. I checked it and it definetly changes to 1 before sending form, however after submitting form I'm getting only

```
test.html?fileToUpload=somefile
```

Without the "variable". Yes I know I should use POST and redirect form to some PHP file but I changed it to GET and html to check what is received in URL.
Any other ways to add "variable" to the form string without adding extra input are welcome.

Comment: the text input needs to have a name="something"

Comment: also, don't upload over GET, it has a character limit, which is very likely bigger than your file. For file uploads, always use POST.

Comment: I forgot about name... thanks, it's working now. GET is only here to test, I'm changing it to POST when everything works.